# What is this cabinet panel plastic clip called?

Tags: cabinets, fastener

I have a panel in my cabinetry that's held into its cutout with plastic clips screwed into the back. The clips are ~15 years old and no longer doing a great job at holding the panel in place, however my local hardware stores haven't seen clips like these so don't sell replacements. I'm not even sure what they're actually called so haven't been able to find replacements online.

Does anyone know what these things are called?

[image]

Comment: Might be a PITA to do, but there should be many ways of attaching the panel.  I am assuming the panel stays in place and is not removed often.

Comment: As for the name I would guess a plastic spring clip.  After 1001 pages you might find the right size, or not.

Comment: I could glue the panel on but I don't know if I'd ever need to remove it to service the kitchen sink the panel's in front of down the road.

Comment: Zillions of possibilities out there. Here’s one: https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/hardware/fasteners/knockdown-hardware/40080-knock-down-panel-connectors?item=00S0401

Comment: a few supermarkets may do the job as replacements

Comment: Those are common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[False Front Clip](https://www.dkhardware.com/hafele-p-01498452-false-front-connector-for-5-openings-product-6530247.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=shopping&utm_campaign=free_listings&srsltid=AfmBOooRgyI9BUR7oyH1_PcXZbdGuiB3LcUwXC67aFNqpPCkICTxAUeYXd0) or cabinet blank clip.

Comment: Thank you! False Front Clip or cabinet blank clip it is!